# Отображение данных по тегам из json на странице

Tags: javascript, html, json

Возник с трудностью с отображением нужных данных. Необходимо, что бы при активной кнопке пушились данные с конкретным тегом (При активной кнопке Франция добавлялись каточки с tag: France и т.д.), а не все.

HTML

```
   <div class="catalog__top_box">
      <button class="catalog__top_box-btn" id="btn-france">Франция</button>
      <button class="catalog__top_box-btn" id="btn-germany">Германия</button>
      <button class="catalog__top_box-btn" id="btn-england">Англия</button>
   </div>
```

js

```
const btnActiveFrance = document.querySelector('#btn-france');

btnActiveFrance.classList.add('active');

const btnActive = document.querySelectorAll('.catalog__top_box button');

btnActive.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', () => {
        btnActive.forEach(e => {
            e.classList.remove('active');
        })
        item.classList.add('active');
    })
})

const catalogBox = document.querySelector("#catalog-box");

getCatalog();

async function getCatalog() {
    const response = await fetch('catalogBox.json');
    const catalogArray = await response.json();

    renderBlog(catalogArray);
}

function renderBlog(catalogArray) {
    catalogArray.forEach(function (item) {
        const catalogHTML = `
            <div class="catalog__card" id="${item.id}">
                <img src="${item.img}" alt="${item.alt}" class="catalog__card_img">
                <p class="catalog__card_author">${item.author}</p>
                <p class="catalog__card_name">${item.name}</p>
                <p class="catalog__card_note">${item.note}</p>
                <p class="catalog__card_price">${item.price}</p>
                <button class="catalog__card_btn">${item.btn}</button>
            </div>
        `;
        catalogBox.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', catalogHTML)
    });
};
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "author": "Марсель Руссо",
        "name": "Охота Амура",
        "note": "Холст, масло (50х80)",
        "price": "14 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/France/France1.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "France",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "author": "Анри Селин",
        "name": "Дама с собачкой",
        "note": "Акрил, бумага (50х80)",
        "price": "16 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/France/France2.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "France",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "author": "Франсуа Дюпон",
        "name": "Процедура",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60)",
        "price": "20 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/France/France3.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "France",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "author": "Луи Детуш",
        "name": "Роза",
        "note": "Бумага, акрил (50х80)",
        "price": "12 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/France/France4.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "France",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "author": "Франсуа Дюпон",
        "name": "Птичья трапеза",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60)",
        "price": "22 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/France/France5.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "France",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "author": "Пьер Моранж",
        "name": "Пейзаж с рыбой",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60) ",
        "price": "20 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/France/France6.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "France",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "author": "Курт Вернер",
        "name": "Над городом",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60)",
        "price": "16 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/Germany/Germany1.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "Germany",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "author": "Макс Рихтер",
        "name": "Птенцы",
        "note": "Холст, масло (50х80) ",
        "price": "14 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/Germany/Germany2.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "Germany",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "author": "Мартин Майер",
        "name": "Среди листьев",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60)",
        "price": "20 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/Germany/Germany3.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "Germany",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "author": "Герман Беккер",
        "name": "Яркая птица",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60)",
        "price": "13 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/Germany/Germany4.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "Germany",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "author": "Вульф Бауэр",
        "name": "Дятлы",
        "note": "Бумага, акрил (50х80)",
        "price": "20 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/Germany/Germany5.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "Germany",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "author": "Вальтер Хартманн",
        "name": "Большие воды",
        "note": "Бумага, акрил (50х80)",
        "price": "23 000 рубб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/Germany/Germany6.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "Germany",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "author": "Пол Смит",
        "name": "Дикий зверь",
        "note": "Акварель, бумага (50х80)",
        "price": "19 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/England/England1.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "England",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "author": "Джон Уайт",
        "name": "Скалистый берег",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60) ",
        "price": "17 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/England/England2.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "England",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "author": "Джим Уотсон",
        "name": "Река и горы",
        "note": "Акварель, бумага (50х80)",
        "price": "20 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/England/England3.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "England",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "author": "Юджин Зиллион",
        "name": "Белый попугай",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60) ",
        "price": "15 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/England/England4.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "England",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "author": "Эрик Гиллман",
        "name": "Ночная рыба",
        "note": "Бумага, акрил (50х80) ",
        "price": "12 500 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/England/England5.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "England",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "author": "Альфред Барр",
        "name": "Рыжий кот",
        "note": "Цветная литография (40х60)",
        "price": "21 000 руб",
        "img": "./img/catalog/England/England6.jpg",
        "alt": "img",
        "tag": "England",
        "btn": "В корзину"
    }
]
```

Comment: можете использовать filter https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter